# How to recover data after Low Level formatting of WD 500gb External HDD

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover data loss from accidental quick format](https://superuser.com/questions/11160/recover-data-loss-from-accidental-quick-format)

I have lost everything on my Passport WD 500gb HDD,and no,there was no back up done :(
I've heard of people who have gone to the ends of the earth to remove formatted data, and its still recoverable. Even HDDs stuffed in fires can be partially recovered.What options do I have? Can I recover it anyhow? Please help me out.
Thanking you all in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [almost](http://superuser.com/questions/11160/recover-data-loss-from-accidental-quick-format) [every](http://superuser.com/questions/6810/best-undelete-tool-for-ntfs-fat) [data-recovery](http://superuser.com/questions/51984/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive) [question](http://superuser.com/questions/148326/formatted-d-partition-by-mistake).

Comment: Low-level formatting? Please specify [what you mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_formatting#Low-level_formatting_.28LLF.29_of_hard_disks). If you overwrote all data with zeros or random patterns, there's no way to get your data back.

Comment: Marked duplicate has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Could always look at How-To Geek's ["Recover Data Like a Forensics Expert Using an Ubuntu Live CE](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) and [Recover Deleted Files on an NTFS Hard Drive from a Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/). Granted there are rediculous ways that actual forensics experts can get data, but hiring them requires you to pour out some serious cash.

Or commit a felony and ask them to recover the data for you while they try and find evidence!

*Disclaimer: Don't do that.*

Comment: I don't think they'd give you a copy of the "evidence", would they?

Comment: Depends on how corrupt the professional and how much capital you have to bribe him with!

Answer (score 0):

If the data was not overwritten, this is the best recovery software I have ever used, bar none.

http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm

If the data was overwritten, nothing can get your data back.